# Must all attributes used in the GROUP BY clause appear in SELECT clause?

Tags: mysql

The following question was given in previous year's papers of a competitive exam for which I'm preparing:

> Must all attributes used in the GROUP BY clause appear in SELECT clause?

Can someone please clarify this doubt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, however if you do use a GROUP BY clause, there are limitations on what you can put into the SELECT clause